# Google Fit issues with some devices

Tags: android, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I created a pedometer that counts/displays steps in real-time, but it doesn't work on some devices. So far it's working perfectly fine on a Nexus 7 tablet and Samsung Galaxy S7, but not on two different Galaxy S4s.

The issue is the steps will not be tracked in the background when the screen is closed. This happens in the Google Fit app as well. The basic idea is I have a data listener that checks for steps and increments the count.

Here's the step count logic.

```
public void buildFitnessClient() {
    // Create the Google API Client
    mClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
            .addApi(Fitness.RECORDING_API)
            .addApi(Fitness.HISTORY_API)
            .addApi(Fitness.SENSORS_API)
            .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ_WRITE))
            .addConnectionCallbacks(
                    new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {

                        @Override
                        public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Connected!!!");
                            // Now you can make calls to the Fitness APIs.  What to do?
                            // Subscribe to some data sources!
                            subscribe();
                            readData();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
                            // If your connection to the sensor gets lost at some point,
                            // you'll be able to determine the reason and react to it here.
                            if (i == GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.CAUSE_NETWORK_LOST) {
                                Log.w(TAG, "Connection lost.  Cause: Network Lost.");
                            } else if (i == GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.CAUSE_SERVICE_DISCONNECTED) {
                                Log.w(TAG, "Connection lost.  Reason: Service Disconnected");
                            }
                        }
                    }
            )
            .enableAutoManage(getActivity(), 0, new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "Google Play services connection failed. Cause: " +
                            result.toString());
                }
            })
            .build();

    //subscribe();

    //readData();
}

/**
 * Record step data by requesting a subscription to background step data.
 */
public void subscribe() {
    // To create a subscription, invoke the Recording API. As soon as the subscription is
    // active, fitness data will start recording.
    Fitness.RecordingApi.subscribe(mClient, DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
            .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(Status status) {
                    if (status.isSuccess()) {
                        if (status.getStatusCode()
                                == FitnessStatusCodes.SUCCESS_ALREADY_SUBSCRIBED) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Existing subscription for activity detected.");
                        } else {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Successfully subscribed!");
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.w(TAG, "There was a problem subscribing.");
                    }
                }
            });
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    String s = presenter.getStepCount();
    mInitialNumberOfSteps = Integer.parseInt(s);

    double cals = (_totalCalories - (mInitialNumberOfSteps * 0.044));
    int bSteps = (int) Math.round(cals);


    double eightyPercent = _totalCalories * 0.8;
    _eighty = (int) Math.round(eightyPercent);

    double sixtyPercent = _totalCalories * 0.6;
    _sixty = (int) Math.round(sixtyPercent);

    double fortyPercent = _totalCalories * 0.4;
    _forty = (int) Math.round(fortyPercent);

    double twentyPercent = _totalCalories * 0.2;
    _twenty = (int) Math.round(twentyPercent);

    if (bSteps <= eighty && bSteps > sixty) {
        _alreadyPlayed = false;
    } else if (bSteps <= sixty && bSteps > forty) {
        _alreadyPlayed = true;
    } else if (bSteps <= forty && bSteps > twenty) {
        _alreadyPlayed = false;
    } else if (bSteps <= twenty && bSteps > 0) {
        _alreadyPlayed = true;
    } else if (bSteps == 0 || bSteps < 0) {
        _alreadyPlayed = false;
    }



    //dispatcher.cancelAll();


    if (presenter.checkPauseBool()) {
        String calsRem = presenter.getCalsRemaining();

        _remCals = Integer.valueOf(calsRem);

        if (!calsRem.equals("0")) {

            _caloriesRemaining.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.crumble_calories_remaining, String.valueOf(calsRem)));
        }
    }

public int startPedometer() {
    listener = new OnDataPointListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataPoint(DataPoint dataPoint) {
            for (Field field : dataPoint.getDataType().getFields()) {
                if (dataPoint.getDataType().equals(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)) {
                    Value val = dataPoint.getValue(field);
                    Log.d("JUNE 12: ", "" + val);

                    presenter.setActiveFlag();

                    if (!presenter.checkPauseBool()) {
                        val.setInt(0);
                        presenter.putPauseBool();
                    }

                    mInitialNumberOfSteps += val.asInt();

                    //readData();

                    //_googleFit = new GoogleFit(getContext());


                    //int googleFitSteps = _googleFit.getSteps(_startTime);


                    if (getActivity() == null) {
                        return;
                    } else if (isAdded()) {
                        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                                        @Override
                                                        public void run() {
                                                            //_dailyStepTotal.setText("Steps: " + mInitialNumberOfSteps);

                                                            double cals = (_totalCalories - (mInitialNumberOfSteps * 0.044));
                                                            _remCals = (int) Math.round(cals);

                                                            if (isAdded()) {
                                                                _caloriesRemaining.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.crumble_calories_remaining, String.valueOf(_remCals)));
                                                            }

                                                            double eightyPercent = _totalCalories * 0.8;
                                                            eighty = (int) Math.round(eightyPercent);

                                                            double sixtyPercent = _totalCalories * 0.6;
                                                            sixty = (int) Math.round(sixtyPercent);

                                                            double fortyPercent = _totalCalories * 0.4;
                                                            forty = (int) Math.round(fortyPercent);

                                                            double twentyPercent = _totalCalories * 0.2;
                                                            twenty = (int) Math.round(twentyPercent);

                                                            if ((_remCals <= eighty && _remCals > sixty) && !_alreadyPlayed) {
                                                                presenter.onBeginCrumbleClick();
                                                                presenter.switchCrumbleImage(two);
                                                                _alreadyPlayed = true;
                                                            } else if ((_remCals <= sixty && _remCals > forty) && _alreadyPlayed) {
                                                                presenter.onBeginCrumbleClick();
                                                                presenter.switchCrumbleImage(three);
                                                                _alreadyPlayed = false;
                                                            } else if ((_remCals <= forty && _remCals > twenty) && !_alreadyPlayed) {
                                                                presenter.onBeginCrumbleClick();
                                                                presenter.switchCrumbleImage(four);
                                                                _alreadyPlayed = true;
                                                            } else if ((_remCals <= twenty && _remCals > 0) && _alreadyPlayed) {
                                                                presenter.onBeginCrumbleClick();
                                                                presenter.switchCrumbleImage(five);
                                                                _alreadyPlayed = false;
                                                            } else if ((_remCals == 0 || _remCals < 0) && !_alreadyPlayed) {
                                                                presenter.clearActiveFoodFlag();
                                                                presenter.addToHistory(_totalCalories);
                                                                presenter.saveSteps("0");
                                                                presenter.updateQueue();
                                                                fireworksAnimation();
                                                                _alreadyPlayed = true;
                                                                getActivity().finish();
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                        );
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    };
    SensorRequest req = new SensorRequest.Builder().setDataType(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA).setSamplingRate(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();
    result = Fitness.SensorsApi.add(mClient, req, listener);

    //Log.d("Steps: ", "" + result);

    return mInitialNumberOfSteps;
}
```

Comment: Are you using a service or just a plain activity? Maybe, since the S4s have less RAM the app could be getting killed in the background?

Comment: No service. I could be wrong but the way I understand it is Google Fit tracks steps once the subscription is started, so I just check for new steps in the onDataPoint() method. It works when the activity is the in the foreground, and works onResume() except for on the Galaxy S4.

Comment: If your app is closed, the onStop or onDestroy method might be called. You could try to debug overriding and using some log inside of those functions and see if they're being called on the S4. Or you could manually kill your app on the S7 and try to see if it still counts the steps after that. If it stops, you're gonna need to use a service to run forever in the background. I'm not sure now that you mentioned that once you're registered it keeps counting, but I'd expect it to close and stop everything in the app.

Comment: It should keep counting when the app is paused according to Google Fit documentation, "Google Fit stores fitness data from active subscriptions even when your app is not running and restores these subscriptions when the system restarts". I'm not canceling the subscription anywhere. I'm going to attempt logging the steps to see what's happening.

Comment: I've tested the app on two S3s, an S7, a Nexus 7 and it works fine. Weirdly the only one it doesn't work on is the S4.